# Filter dataframe for values contained in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called "df_business".  I have sample from the data frame below.  I'd like to filter the dataframe for records which contain "Restaurant" in the categories column.  Can anyone suggest how to do that?

```
Code:

print(df_business[1:3])


Sample Data:

               address                                         attributes  \
1       2824 Milton Rd  {u'GoodForMeal': {u'dessert': False, u'latenig...   
2  337 Danforth Avenue  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   

              business_id                                         categories  \
1  mLwM-h2YhXl2NCgdS84_Bw  [Food, Soul Food, Convenience Stores, Restaura...   
2  v2WhjAB3PIBA8J8VxG3wEg                               [Food, Coffee & Tea]   

        city                                              hours  is_open  \
1  Charlotte  {u'Monday': u'10:00-22:00', u'Tuesday': u'10:0...        0   
2    Toronto  {u'Monday': u'10:00-19:00', u'Tuesday': u'10:0...        0   

    latitude  longitude                                name neighborhood  \
1  35.236870 -80.741976  South Florida Style Chicken & Ribs     Eastland   
2  43.677126 -79.353285                    The Tea Emporium    Riverdale   

  postal_code  review_count  stars state  
1       28215             4    4.5    NC  
2     M4K 1N7             7    4.5    ON
```

Comment: What is `df_business['categories'].apply(type)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `in` parameter if values in `categories` are lists:

```
df_business = df_business[df_business['categories'].apply(lambda x: 'Restaurant' in x)]
```

Or:

```
df_business = df_business[df_business['categories'].astype(str).str.contains('Restaurant')]
```

Sample:

```
df_business = pd.DataFrame({'categories':[['Restaurant','Food'],['Food']],
                            'review_count':[4,7]})

print (df_business)
           categories  review_count
0  [Restaurant, Food]             4
1              [Food]             7

df_business = df_business[df_business['categories'].apply(lambda x: 'Restaurant' in x)]
print (df_business)
           categories  review_count
0  [Restaurant, Food]             4
```

Comment: Thank you all, these are all great answers!  I think I like the astype(str).str.contains('Restaurant')] solution best because it's simplest to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Convert your `categories` column to string and use `str.contains`:

```
m = df_business['categories'].astype(str).str.contains('Restaurant')
df_business = df_business.loc[m]
```

If you're worried about partial matches, it might make some sense to add word boundary checks to your regex:

```
r'\bRestaurant\b'
```

This should be a little more tolerant against false positives.

---

Borrowing from [jez' data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46924895/4909087) (thank you!):

```
In [1864]: df_business

           categories  review_count
0  [Restaurant, Food]             4
1              [Food]             7


m = df_business['categories'].astype(str).str.contains(r'\bRestaurant\b')
m

0     True
1    False
Name: categories, dtype: bool

df_business = df_business.loc[m]
df_business

           categories  review_count
0  [Restaurant, Food]             4
```

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
Combine all list elements together and look for `'Restaurant'`

```
df_business[
    df_business.categories.str.join('').str.contains('Restaurant')]

           categories  review_count
0  [Restaurant, Food]             4
```

---

**Option 2**
Find index values where `'Restaurant'` is in the list

```
mask = np.concatenate(df_business.categories) == 'Restaurant'
idx = df_business.index.repeat(df_business.categories.str.len())
df_business.loc[np.unique(idx[mask])]

           categories  review_count
0  [Restaurant, Food]             4
```

---

**Setup**
*Borrowed from @jezrael*

```
df_business = pd.DataFrame({'categories':[['Restaurant','Food'],['Food']],
                            'review_count':[4,7]})
```